# Contract deployment: <UnrecognizedContract> during hardhat test deployment

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, hardhat

Im getting UnrecognizedContract when I deployed my token. Not sure what the problem is but here is the code here with deploy.js

```
  async function main () {
  //Fetch contract to deploy
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")

  //Deploy Contract
  const token = await Token.deploy() 
  await token.deployed()
  console.log (`Token Deployed to: ${token.address}`)
}

main()
  .then (() => process.exit (0))
  .catch ((error) => {
    console.error (error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Any fixes would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, found out that the import of hardhat console.sol was not working. Please check your script for import or any other errors. if the smart contract gets deployed with  then the execution of the smart contract does not work. I mainly use hardhat framework to compile and deploy the smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console. Sol";
```

**Problem**

```
Contract deployment: <UnrecognizedContract>
```

**Fix**

After fixing the import on the smart contract, or any other errors on the smart contract

create a backup of the /src/artifacts folder and then delete this folder.

re-compile

> npx hardhat compile

re-deploy

> npx hardhat run scripts/yourdeploymentscript.js

check deployment console you should see the correct output of the smart contract.

```
Contract deployment: YourContractName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have started your node before writing out the script that is

> `npx hardhat node`

Turn off the node and again turn it on by writing the above code. In my condition it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dutchAuction = await deploy("WFCoin", {
contract: "WFCoin",
from: deployer,
args: args,
log: true,
waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 6,});
```

I was following a tutorial and the problem was the last line, that is,

`waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 6`

Removing that worked for me